# Import CSV file in Arabic using Prestashop 1.6

Tags: csv, encode, arabic, prestashop-1.6

I have a CSV file with a list of products and I'm trying to import them from back office.

My website include French and Arabic language.

I succeeded importing product in French but I'm having issue with Arabic language is give me name of product in interregation points :(

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**

Hello finally i found the solution about issue the saved csv in UTF8 you can follow this steps:

**1. In Microsoft Excel, open the *.xlsx file.**

**2. Select Menu | Save As.**

**3. Enter any name for your file.**

**4. Under "Save as type," select Unicode Text.**

**5. Click Save.**

**6. Open your saved file in Microsoft Notepad.**

**7. Replace all tab characters with commas (",").**

**Select a tab character (select and copy the space between two column headers)
Open the "Find and Replace" window (Press Ctrl+H) and replace all tab characters with comma .**

**8. Click Save As.**

**9. Name the file, and change the Encoding: to UTF-8.**

**10. Change the file extension from "*.txt" to "*.csv".**

**11. Click Save.**

**12. Open the .csv file in Excel to view your data.**